# Python return list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, object

```
class alexicon(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.directions = ['north', 'south', 'west', 'east', 'up', 'down']
    self.items = []

def scan(self, words):
    self.word = words.split()
    # direction
    self.direction_word = [i for i in self.word if i in self.directions]
    self.direction_list = []
    for x in self.direction_word:
        self.direction_list.append(('direction', '%s' %(x)) )
    if self.direction_list != []:
        self.items.extend(self.direction_list)
    else:
        pass
   return self.items

lexicon = alexicon()
result = lexicon.scan('north')
print result
```

Why print result get a 'None'? How can I get the items list?
But if I print the lexicon.items I can get the right list(There are elements in that list).

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Returns list with elements:- [('direction', 'north')], assuming that indentations are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the indentations:

```
class alexicon(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.directions = ['north', 'south', 'west', 'east', 'up', 'down']
        self.items = []

    def scan(self, words):
        self.word = words.split()
# direction
        self.direction_word = [i for i in self.word if i in self.directions]
        self.direction_list = []
        for x in self.direction_word:
            self.direction_list.append(('direction', '%s' %(x)) )
        if self.direction_list != []:
            self.items.extend(self.direction_list)
        else:
            pass
        return(self.items)

lexicon = alexicon()
result = lexicon.scan('north')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('direction', 'north')]
```

Comment: @J.Zeng: Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: Thanks. It's a part of my code. When I run this part I got the right list..

Comment: So the problem is at another part..I am going to find it out..Thank you again.

Comment: @J.Zeng: As you got the desired answer. Please confirm by accepting it